# Flip the order of X and Y in MACRO(X)(Y)

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I have a C++ macro-based DSL that defines a macro like this:

```
#define RETURNS(...) \
    enable_if_t<__VA_ARGS__ WHEN

#define WHEN(...) \
    , EAT_ ## __VA_ARGS__ >

#define EAT_requires
```

This is for use like:

```
template<class T>
auto some_function(T t) ->
    RETURNS(int)
        (requires SomeConcept<T>)
```

Which expands to:

```
template<class T>
auto some_function(T t) ->
    enable_if_t<int, SomeConcept<T>>
```

(When C++20 concepts are enabled, this expands to a real `requires` clause.)

I would prefer the order of the parameters to be flipped. That is, I would like it to generate this:

```
template<class T>
auto some_function(T t) ->
    enable_if_t<SomeConcept<T>, int>
```

I think it's not possible. Can some clever PP hacker prove me wrong?

Comment: *Why* macros? There are almost always better ways.

Comment: Would just defining a new `template<A,B> enable_if_t_reversed<A,B> : enable_if_t<B,A>` work?

Comment: "_Why_ macros?"

-- Looks like you missed the fact that this is a portability macro that expands to something else when C++20 concepts are supported.

"Would just defining a new `template<A,B> enable_if_t_reversed<A,B> : enable_if_t<B,A>` work?"

-- That's what I'm currently doing, and it's not terrible, but it forces the evaluation of type `B` even when `A` is `false`. If I can find a way to reorder the arguments, I can make compile-times better.

Comment: @EricNiebler but, there's no short-circuiting inside `enable_if_t` -- reversing the arguments changes nothing.

Comment: @Quentin That's what I thought too, and yet, see [this example](https://godbolt.org/z/qKBSq1). Edited it slightly from what Eric originally showed me. Calling `foo` is fine, calling `bar` is a hard error.

Comment: @Barry If I read that correctly, `using fast_enable_if_t` forces the instantiation of `hard_error_t<T>`. That's puzzling indeed, but unless my brain is fried that's independent from the order of the arguments, isn't it?

Comment: @Quentin Yeah, it's not order of arguments based. It's that `fast_enable_if<false>::sfinae` is already a substitution failure - and we instantiate left-to-right. Putting the condition first lets you get away with that. (Also in this case we're not trying to avoid instantiating due to hard errors, we're trying to avoid instantiating due to extra compile time work)

Comment: @Barry oooooh I see, that clicked. I still don't see why merely mentioning `hard_error_t<T>` instantiates it, but alright. In particular, it doesn't even need to be defined...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is tolerable to omit an open paren, you can achieve it like this:

```
#define UNWRAP(...) __VA_ARGS__

#define RETURNS(...) \
    WHEN ((__VA_ARGS__),

#define WHEN(x, ...) \
    enable_if_t<EAT_ ## __VA_ARGS__, UNWRAP x>

#define EAT_requires

template<class T>
auto some_function(T t) ->
    RETURNS(pair<int, int>)
        requires SomeConcept<T, int>)
```

Input:

```
template<class T>
auto some_function(T t) ->
    RETURNS(pair<int, int>)
        requires SomeConcept<T, int>)
```

Output:

```
template<class T>
auto some_function(T t) ->
    enable_if_t< SomeConcept<T, int>, pair<int, int> >
```

Comment: Nice hack, but IDE will not happy.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you just use something like

```
template<class T,bool B>
using reverse_enable_if_t=enable_if_t<B,T>;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another take on this is:

```
#define RETURNS(...) REVERSE_ENABLE_IF_T((__VA_ARGS__))
#define REQUIRES ),(
#define UNWRAP(...) __VA_ARGS__        
#define REVERSE_ENABLE_IF_T(PT,PB) enable_if_t<UNWRAP PB,UNWRAP PT>
```

which allows for the following parens-balanced syntax:

```
template<class T>
auto some_function(T t) ->
  RETURNS(pair<int, int> REQUIRES SomeConcept<T, int>);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that does not require unmatched parenthesis, but requires adding an EVAL macro around the entire thing:

```
#define EVAL( ... )  EVAL1( __VA_ARGS__ )
#define EVAL1( ... ) EVAL0( EVAL0( EVAL0( __VA_ARGS__ ) ) )
#define EVAL0( ... ) __VA_ARGS__

#define EMPTY()
#define DEFER( ... ) __VA_ARGS__ EMPTY()

#define EAT_requires
#define SWAP( X, Y )   enable_if_t<EAT_##Y, X>
#define RETURNS( X )   DEFER( SWAP )( X, ADD_PAREN
#define ADD_PAREN( Y ) Y )
```

You can then write the following:

```
EVAL(
  template<class T>
  auto some_function(T t) ->
    RETURNS(int)
      (requires SomeConcept<T>)
)
```

and it produces:

```
template<class T>
auto some_function( T t ) ->
  enable_if_t<SomeConcept<T>, int>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to avoid having to wrap the declaration in an `EVAL` macro.